# How can I use the word example as an adjective?

Tags: adjectives

How can I use the word "example" as an adjective? 
I want to say something like *"Give 5 **example** **words** for the letter B"*.

Is that Ok to use it that way or I have to change something here (because it *<=the word "example">* is a noun that can be also plural)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *example* this way that you used. It's called a [noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct) - and it's likely the most common and idiomatic way to express what you want.